# Convert an array of UInt64 into a BitVector

Tags: arrays, julia, bitset

I've recently discovered that I can get the 'backing array' of `UInt64` for a `BitVector` using `chunks`. However, I would like to go the opposite way - given a one-dimensional array of `UInt64`, construct a `BitVector` using some function `foo` such that

`foo(x.chunks) == x`

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/i-have-vector-uint8-i-need-bitvector/2286/4) work?

```
function foo(v::Vector{UInt64})
    siz = sizeof(v)
    bv = falses(siz << 6)
    unsafe_copyto!(reinterpret(Ptr{UInt64}, pointer(bv.chunks)), pointer(v), siz)
    bv
end
```

They also provide an overload to set the number of bits in the resulting `BitVector` if required.

EDIT: The use of `unsafe_copyto!` indicates that the code may not perform extensive safety checks and relies on low-level memory operations. Care should be taken when using such functions to ensure that memory is accessed and manipulated safely.

Another way of doing what you're asking:

```
function bar{T}(v::Vector{T})
    siz = sizeof(T) * length(v) * 8  # Calculate size in bits
    bv = BitVector(siz)              # Create a BitVector of the appropriate size
    bv .= reinterpret(BitArray, v)   # Use a broadcast assignment to copy the data
    return bv
end
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use ``falses`` here instead of just using ``BitArray(siz << 3, 1)``? That way, we don't have to zero the data (which is gonna be overwritten anyway). Also, why ``siz << 3``? Shouldn't it be ``siz << 6``, or am I missing something?

Comment: @KozRoss You're right it should be `siz << 6` and I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sometimes, asking for an empty array of zeros is faster than asking for an uninitialized array, if the underlying implementation uses [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) instead of [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). (calloc doesn't allocate right away.)